# Ignore camelcase check for particular variable in jshint

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jshint, code-cleanup

We have used few global variables which are not camel case. Ex. `lang_code`.

We can not make this variable camel case.

I know there are ways to avoid checking camel case at file level and function level.

But problem with those is that will avoid checking all the variables for camel case.

I want a way to avoid checking camel case only for particular variables.

Is there any way we can do that ?

Comment: Maybe consider using a more flexible modern linter like ESLint, and then you can use `// eslint-disable-line`

Comment: @CertainPerformance This will disable the lint for line. If we have used that variable at many places then that means we have to use this command every place where it is used. Apart from this when we stop lint for a line, it will not catch other lint warnings on same line.

Comment: No, you only have to disable the rule when the variable is defined, not everywhere it's used. You can disable *only* the `camelCase` rule for that line, too